# Why does this assertion fail when comparing exceptions?

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception

I have a test method that asserts an expected exception equals the thrown exception but it fails, but the error message says they are the same

```
@IsTest
private static void isThrowable() {
    // given
    IllegalArgumentException ex = new IllegalArgumentException();

    // when
    IllegalArgumentException thrownException;
    try {
        throw ex;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        thrownException = e;
    }

    // then
    System.assertEquals(ex, thrownException);
}
```

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: IllegalArgumentException:[]: Script-thrown exception, Actual: IllegalArgumentException:[]: Script-thrown exception
> Class.enigma.IllegalArgumentExceptionTest.isThrowable: line 17, column 1

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior because you are comparing a System Exception against the Exception thrown from your own Class.

**System Exception != Class throwns Exception** and that's what the error clearly says.

Read the message again and specifically the one in highlighted and this will tell you the difference.

> Expected: IllegalArgumentException:[]: Script-thrown exception

> Actual: IllegalArgumentException:[]: Script-thrown exception
> **Class.enigma.IllegalArgumentExceptionTest.isThrowable: line 17, column 1**

You can simply compare its type, which should make your tests happy.

```
@isTest
private class TestCls {

@IsTest
private static void isThrowable() {
    // given
    IllegalArgumentException ex = new IllegalArgumentException();

    // when
    IllegalArgumentException thrownException;
    try {
        throw ex;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        thrownException = e;
    }

    // then
    System.assertEquals(thrownException.getTypeName(), ex.getTypeName());
    }

}
```

Comment: It's still not quite clear to me how the error message makes this clear this is a System exception. The bolded portion of the error message contains the line it failed on, it doesn't mention anything about it being a System exception.

Comment: It does say Class.enigma.IllegalArgumentExceptionTest while what you are comparing against is System.IllegalArgumentExceptionTest

Comment: Sorry this still isn't clear. I have a custom exception class called `IllegalArgumentException` and the class this test is contained in is called `IllegalArgumentExceptionTest`.

Comment: Nevermind, I had no idea there is a standard `IllegalArgumentException` class

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm